# Find strings in file1, count occurrences in file2

Tags: shell-script, search, string

I have `file1.txt` with string values such as

```
New Drug Application
Drug Product
Dosing instructions
```

I need to count how often these strings occur in `file2.txt` with data such as

```
Regulatory New Drug Application for Drug Product after testing of Dosing instructions for all new studies.
```

The commands I have used are;

```
foreach string ( `cat terms.txt` )
foreach? echo $string >>out.txt
foreach? grep $string data.txt | wc >>out.txt
end
```

The `out.txt` will not return the complete string with spaces. Instead it returns data such as:

```
The -1
New -2
Application -1
etc.
```

I have tried adding quotes and forward slashes to the terms in my data files, `egrep`, `fgrep` - to no avail. How do I get the data I want from these two files?

Comment: This worked like a charm - simple and straightforward. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
fgrep -of file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Beware that this will only find the exact phrases.  If the spacing is different, it won't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use IFS (Internal Field Separator), and assign the $'\n' to it, meaning that only newlines are the valid separator. Also, to detect multiple occurrences of the same key in the content, we could use grep -o option. Example bash script could be like the following:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for string in `cat key.txt`
do
   $string >> out.txt
   grep -o $string content.txt | wc -l >> out.txt
done
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but it does look like you're trying to reinvent `grep -f …`. This reports strings present multiple times on the same line only once.

Comment: The reason I add IFS is to allow bash for loop to catch multiple words instead of single word for each input file line, which is one of the issue Suzanne encountered. As for the miscounting about same line multiple occurrence, I have updated the answer to use grep -o. Thanx for your comments:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grep the entire line.
This can be done as follows -

```
    x=1
    len=$(wc -l file1.txt | awk '{print $1}')
    while [ $x -le $len ] 
    do
       #pat=$(head -$x  file1.txt | tail -1)  << slow hence changed
       pat=$(sed "${x}q;d" $1)
       #cnt=$(grep -c "$pat" file2.txt) < Edited to count all matches 
       cnt=$(grep -o "$pat" file2.txt| wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
       echo "$pat        $cnt"
       x=$(expr $x + 1)
    done
```

EDITED : for both speedup and counting multiple occurences on the same line

Comment: I just saw at  that instead of head/tail you can use  pat=$(sed "${x}q;d" $1) .  You can refer to this answer -http://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431/3935925.   I have edited the code snippet accordingly

Comment: If a line contains multiple occurrences of the same string, it'll be counted only once.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Gilles. I have modified the grep statement to count all the occurrences...